# Executing stored procedures asynchronously using tasks in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I have a stored procedure which is calling **20-30 stored procedures**. I need these stored procedures to **run asynchronously**. From what I have read, it seems like executing those stored procedures using SQL tasks in SSIS is the appropriate way to do it.

I have installed required software but I am completely new to it.Can I please get some directions on how to do it? i.e run stored procedures asynchronously using SQL tasks in **SSIS**,please? Since I am completely new to it,please try to elaborate as much as possible as I have no prior knowledge of  this. It will be a great help.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you creating duplicate questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29316309/using-ssis-package-to-execute-stored-procedures-asynchrnously

Comment: "From what I have read" point me to the link please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of SSIS I think you might want to look into SQL Server Service Broker. This lets you send messages asynchronously. See [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3880191/SQL-Server-Service-Broker---An-Introduction.htm) or [here](http://gavindraper.com/2012/06/03/sql-server-service-broker-explained/) for a start.

MSMQ or RabbitMQ may also be options you should consider.

Answer (score 1):

Throw Execute SQL tasks into the control flow and don't link them to each other. Any task without a preceeding task will run asychronously.

Executing 20 - 30 Stored procedures in parallel would bring you a lot of workload. I say think twice about it. I have a developer who did that with a custom written windows service, i am facing resorce_semaphore wait types every time they ran.